# Connect Time out not working as expected

Tags: java, asynchttpclient

I am trying to connect to a remote server and have set the connect timeout to 120 seconds. Sometimes it connects, while sometimes it throws us Connect timeout even before trying for 2 mins.

```
setConnectTimeout(120000);
setReadTimeout(120000);
```

I am using AsyncHttpClientConfig for setting these properties.

Below is the error :

> java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.net.ConnectException:
>   connection timed out:   at
>   com.ning.http.client.providers.netty.future.NettyResponseFuture.abort(NettyResponseFuture.java:231)
>     at
>   com.ning.http.client.providers.netty.request.NettyConnectListener.onFutureFailure(NettyConnectListener.java:137)
>     at
>   com.ning.http.client.providers.netty.request.NettyConnectListener.operationComplete(NettyConnectListener.java:145)
>     at
>   org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelFuture.notifyListener(DefaultChannelFuture.java:409)
>     at
>   org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelFuture.notifyListeners(DefaultChannelFuture.java:400)
>     at
>   org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelFuture.setFailure(DefaultChannelFuture.java:362)
>     at
>   org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioClientBoss.processConnectTimeout(NioClientBoss.java:142)
>     at
>   org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioClientBoss.process(NioClientBoss.java:83)
>     at
>   org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioSelector.run(AbstractNioSelector.java:337)
>     at
>   org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioClientBoss.run(NioClientBoss.java:42)
>     at
>   org.jboss.netty.util.ThreadRenamingRunnable.run(ThreadRenamingRunnable.java:108)
>     at
>   org.jboss.netty.util.internal.DeadLockProofWorker$1.run(DeadLockProofWorker.java:42)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) Caused by:
>   java.net.ConnectException: connection timed out:   at
>   com.ning.http.client.providers.netty.request.NettyConnectListener.onFutureFailure(NettyConnectListener.java:133)
>     ... 13 more Caused by:
>   org.jboss.netty.channel.ConnectTimeoutException: connection timed out:
>       at
>   org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioClientBoss.processConnectTimeout(NioClientBoss.java:139)
>     ... 8 more

Comment: Use telnet to check whether it is the issue in your program or connection issue

Comment: Its not an issue with the program. It sometimes connects and sometimes doesnt.

Comment: You can confirm your suspicions by using telnet to connect to the server at least 10 times. Should telnet has the same problem you will be sure that is the connection issue.

Comment: Telnet doesn't give an error for the particular server and port.

Comment: Your question is way to vague. Please mention the version and the provider (Netty or Grizzly) you're using. If you're using an old version, please update. If issue still happens with latest version, please provide a reproducer and open an issue on github: https://github.com/AsyncHttpClient/async-http-client/issues

Comment: I am using netty 3.10.5

Comment: Which could mean anywhere between AHC 1.9.32 and 1.9.38, or you could even be using an older version and forcefully upgraded Netty. Latest AHC is  2.0.3. Again, which AHC version do you use and have you tried upgrading?

Comment: Tried using 1.9.38 yesterday and It worked all day.. But now again seems to have issue. Will try 2.0.3